# React Native dropdown picker showing only 3 items at a time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using React Native Dropdown picker to display a list of items. however I have noticed that the dropdown displays only 3 items at a time however it has more than 3 in that object, my code is as follows:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {Images} from '../../../assets/index';
import {getMonthDate} from '../../../utils/dateUtils';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import DaysInAWeek from './DaysInAWeek';
export default function Header(props) {
  const {navigation} = props;
  const [daysInAWeek, setDaysInAWeek] = useState([]);
  const end_ts = props.data.end_ts * 1000;
  const start_ts = props.data.start_ts * 1000;
  console.log('---header props', props);
  const [] = useState(null);

  let interval = 7 * 86400000;
  let arr = [];
  let new_arr = [];
  for (let i = start_ts; i < end_ts; i = i + interval) {
    arr.push(i);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    new_arr.push(arr.slice(i, i + 2));
  }

  let dateArr = [];

  for (let a of new_arr) {
    let label;
    if (a.length > 1) {
      label = getMonthDate(new Date(a[0])) + '-' + getMonthDate(new Date(a[1]));
    } else {
      label = `${getMonthDate(new Date(a[0]))}`;
    }
    let obj = {
      label,
      value: a,
    };
    dateArr.push(obj);
  }

  function onValSelect(val) {
    console.log('VALL', val);

    if (val.length > 1) {
      let arr = [];
      for (let i = val[0]; i <= val[1]; i += 86400000) {
        let date = i;
        arr.push(date);
      }

      console.log('final arr', arr);
      setDaysInAWeek(arr);
    } else {
      console.log('single date', val.value);
      setDaysInAWeek(getDay(new Date(val.value)));
    }
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#FE017E',
          width: '100%',
          height: 40,
          padding: 10,
        }}
        underlayColor="transparent"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
        <Image source={Images.back_icon} style={{width: 18, height: 18}} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {dateArr && (
        <DropDownPicker
          onChangeItem={(value) => {
            onValSelect(value.value);
          }}
          items={dateArr}
          containerStyle={{
            marginLeft: '10%',
            marginTop: '-10%',
            marginBottom: 10,
            height: 40,
          }}
          dropDownStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            marginLeft: 40,
            borderColor: 'grey',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderBottomEndRadius: 0,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
            borderBottomStartRadius: 0,
            borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
            minWidth: 100,
            maxWidth: 150,
          }}
          itemStyle={{
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: 16,
            borderColor: '#FE017E',
          }}
          placeholder={dateArr[0]?.label}
          placeholderStyle={{
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontSize: 12,
            color: '#fff',
          }}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#FE017E',
            borderBottomEndRadius: 0,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
            borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
            borderBottomStartRadius: 0,
            borderTopEndRadius: 0,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
            borderRadius: 0,
            borderColor: '#FE017E',
            minWidth: 100,
            maxWidth: 150,
          }}
          labelStyle={{
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontSize: 12,
            color: '#000',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          }}
          arrowColor={'white'}
          activeLabelStyle={{color: '#FE017E'}}
          selectedLabelStyle={{color: 'white'}}
        />
      )}
      <DaysInAWeek
        daysInAWeek={daysInAWeek}
        timestampRetrieved={props.timestampRetrieved}
        daysInAWeekTimestamp={props.daysInAWeekTimestamp}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

But I want to display all the items in the object, could anyone help to fix this?
Any leads would be great

Answer (score 3):

You're unable to see the remaining items because by default react-native-dropdown-picker has dropDownMaxHeight={150}

```
<DropDownPicker
      dropDownMaxHeight={1500}
      onChangeItem={(value) => {
        onValSelect(value.value);
      }}
      items={dateArr}
      containerStyle={{
        marginLeft: '10%',
        marginTop: '-10%',
        marginBottom: 10,
        height: 40,
      }}
      dropDownStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        marginLeft: 40,
        borderColor: 'grey',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderBottomEndRadius: 0,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
        borderBottomStartRadius: 0,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 150,
      }}
      itemStyle={{
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 16,
        borderColor: '#FE017E',
      }}
      placeholder={dateArr[0]?.label}
      placeholderStyle={{
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        fontSize: 12,
        color: '#fff',
      }}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#FE017E',
        borderBottomEndRadius: 0,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
        borderBottomStartRadius: 0,
        borderTopEndRadius: 0,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
        borderRadius: 0,
        borderColor: '#FE017E',
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 150,
      }}
      labelStyle={{
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        fontSize: 12,
        color: '#000',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      }}
      arrowColor={'white'}
      activeLabelStyle={{color: '#FE017E'}}
      selectedLabelStyle={{color: 'white'}}
    />
```

Adjust the dropDownMaxHeight prop to fit your necessity

Answer (score 1):

Change DropDownPicker container height.
ex :

```
<DropDownPicker
    items={data}
    containerStyle={{height: 100}}
    style={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
    itemStyle={{
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    }}
    dropDownStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
   
/>
```

Comment: containerStyle={{height: 100}} , did the job just fine but you might have to play around with marginTop and marginBottom by negating them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change maxHeight. Example:

```
<DropDownPicker
    maxHeight={2000}
    containerStyle={{width: wp('90%'), marginTop: hp('2%')}}
    max={6}
    open={open}
    value={value}
    items={items}
    setOpen={setOpen}
    setValue={setValue}
    setItems={setItems}
    onChangeValue={(value) => regionToParent(value)} />
```